# wxWindows (Python and C++) recognizing left vs right mod keys

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm working on a wxPython app to write out key binds for a game that can bind Left-Shift, -Ctrl, and -Alt separately from Right-Shift etc.

I can use keyEvent.ShiftDown() etc to discover whether shift is down, but apparently I need to rummage around inside keyEvent.GetRawKeyFlags() if I want info on whether it's left or right.  The docs offer a little help:

> Under MSW, the raw flags are just the value of lParam parameter of the
> corresponding message.
>
> Under GTK, the raw flags contain the hardware_keycode field of the
> corresponding GDK event.
>
> Under macOS, the raw flags contain the modifiers state.

But I'm in over my head as far as finding a nice list of the possible "lParam parameter of the corresponding message" values, etc.  I found a couple lists that didn't work;  I think they were probably C#-specific and/or outdated.

I figure my next step is to go traipse through the wxWidgets C++ code itself and see if I can make sense of it, or just trial-and-error 32 bits' worth of flags, but I thought I'd see if y'all had any experience with this and could point me in the right direction.

(In my code, below, I know that my modKeyFlags values are not remotely binary-flag-shaped;  this part is in transition from "==" to "&" but I never found lists of flags to finish the job.  You can see where this is trying to go, I hope.)

```
if wx.Platform == '__WXMSW__':    
    modKeyFlags = {    
        'LSHIFT': 160, 'RSHIFT': 161,    
        'LCTRL' : 162, 'RCTRL' : 163,    
        'LAlT'  : 164, 'RALT'  : 165,    
    }    
elif wx.Platform == '__WXX11_':    
    modKeyFlags = {    
        'LSHIFT': 65505, 'RSHIFT': 65506,    
        'LCTRL' : 65507, 'RCTRL' : 65508,    
        'LALT'  : 65513, 'RALT'  : 65514    
    }    
elif wx.Platform == '__WXMAC__':    
    pass    

# ... more stuff, then inside event handler:

        # check for each modifier key
        if (event.ShiftDown()) :
            if SeparateLR and modKeyFlags:
                if isinstance(event, wx.KeyEvent):
                    rawFlags = event.GetRawKeyFlags()
                    if   (rawFlags & modKeyFlags['LSHIFT']): self.ShiftText = "LSHIFT+"
                    elif (rawFlags & modKeyFlags['RSHIFT']): self.ShiftText = "RSHIFT+"
            else:
                self.ShiftText = "SHIFT+"

# ... checks for CTRL and ALT
```

Any info on the where to find the *correct* lists of key events' raw key flags for any of WXMSW, WXX11, and WXMAC would be immensely helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: can you try and run the `keyboard` sample?

Comment: I had tried it, but not -quite- made the leap of doing binary math on the two large decimal numbers that showed up.  Subtracting one from the other and then bin(the_difference), I suddenly have just a couple flags to choose from and can trial-and-error my way to it easily.  Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 0):

Using the "Keyboard Events" page of the wxpython demo, I can see the decimal representation of the RawFlags that the event got.  Taking those decimal numbers, subtracting the smaller from the larger, and then converting the difference to binary, I get, for instance, 0b11000000000000000000 and now I just have to trial-and-error those two flags.

<sub>*Added on behalf of the question author.*</sub>